# PHP MySQL attendance list for guests

Tags: php, mysql, post, checkbox

I'm writing a attendance list which I want to use for an upcoming event.

When a person log onto the website it can select if he/she and others will be present at the event.

```
if ($res && mysql_num_rows($res) >= 1)
{
     echo '<form method="post" action="guest.php">';
     echo '<table border="10">
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td>Present</td>
        </tr>';

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo '<tr>
            <td>'.$row['guestId']." ".$row['firstName'].'</td>
            <td><input type=\'checkbox\' name=\'present[]\' value='.$row['guestId'].'></td>
        </tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">';

} else {
    echo 'No data found!';
}
```

Here I'm writing the `guestId` into the value which I use to write it into the database:

```
    if( isset($_POST['present']) ) {
        foreach($_POST['present'] as $value){
            $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO present (gastId, present) VALUES (".$value.", 1)");
            $resultadd=mysql_query($query) or die("Errore insert G: ".mysql_error());
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Because I can't imagine that this is the correct way.

Comment: Yes, escape your input variables and use `mysqli_*`.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could insert multiple rows with one query:

```
INSERT INTO present 
(gastId, present)
VALUES
( 1, 1 ),
( 2, 0 ),
( 3, 1 )
```

Or you could use mysqli and prepared statements:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(/* Connection information here */);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO present (gastId, present) VALUES ( ?, 1 )");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $value);
foreach($_POST['present'] as $value) {
   $stmt->execute();
}
$stmt->close();
$mysqli->close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your  Code it's not bad, there are a lot of different ways to do that.

I would recommend you to take a look to the MVC (model-view-controller) if you are going to create a project, here you have a tutorial : http://www.nathandavison.com/posts/view/11/custom-php-mvc-tutorial-part-1-introduction

Also there are some Frameworks like codeigniter, cakePHP,YII ( http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) that will hep you to make a MVC app, also it's more organized, OOP, safety.

**EDIT:** as a @MadaraUchiha recommendation, here it's a link to use PDO, they are a safeties: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: He's using tables for layout and `mysql_*`. I'd call that code "bad".

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I edited it, it was ok because it suppose to work, but I changed it, thanks